# Javascript: How to retrieve a value from a JSON array having multiple nodes and arrays based on condition?

Tags: javascript

I have JSON data that is in the format below. I need to get the store name corresponding to the one which has specialDeal as true in "Non Veg". (NOTE: Only one of the stores will have specialDeal as true and also please note the content inside nonVeg is not an array). How will I retrieve it? Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "Veg": {
    "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
    "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
    "FundDetails":[
      {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""},
      {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""}
    ]
  },
  "Non Veg": {
    "chicken":[
      {
        "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
        "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
        "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
        "FundDetails":[
          {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""},
          {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""}
        ]
      },
      {
        "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
        "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
        "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
        "FundDetails":[
          {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""},
          {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "fish":[
      {
        "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
        "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
        "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
        "FundDetails":[
          {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""},
          {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""}
        ]
      },
      {
        "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
        "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
        "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
        "FundDetails":[
          {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""},
          {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "egg":[
      {
        "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
        "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
        "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
        "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""
      },
      {
        "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
        "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
        "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
        "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""
      }
    ]
  },
  "isMember":"Y",
  "orderId":""
}
```

Here's the code I've tried:

```
var nonveg = DealsJSON.Non Veg; //where JSON is our json data
for (var key in nonveg) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nonveg[key].length; i++) {
        var amountObj = nonveg[key][i];
        if (amountObj['specialDeal'] == true) {
            console.log(amountObj['Store']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? Where are you running into trouble? (And in the quoted JSON, there *is* no `specialDeal` that's `true`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  i just gave a sample json. any one of the specialDeal will be true. The following is the code i tried  but not gtng results. may be because the content inside nonved is not in an array. Can u help.....  'code'                                                                                              var nonveg = DealsJSON.Non Veg; //where JSON is our json data

for(var key in nonveg) {    
  for(var i=0; i<nonveg[key].length; i++) { 
     var amountObj = nonveg[key][i];
     if(amountObj['specialDeal']== true){ 
        console.log(amountObj['Store']);
     }
  }
}

Comment: @ JohnJohny: To improve your question, use the "edit" link and put the code there. I've done it for you this time, since you're new here. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot.. can u help me with the code now?

Comment: One more thing. see the Non Veg object does not contain an array it. The objects inside that are not given in [] but given inside {}. Does that matter?

Comment: @ JohnJohny: `[]` is for defining arrays. `{}` is for defining objects that aren't arrays. Details: http://json.org (If you have a PHP background, forget the PHP use of the word "array" for things that aren't keyed numerically. PHP uses the term "array" in a very confusing way, shorthand for "associative array", which is better termed "dictionary" or "map". In JavaScript, dictionaries/maps are simply objects.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine other than:

```
var nonveg = DealsJSON.Non Veg;
```

...which is a syntax error. Property literals can't have spaces in them, even though property *names* can. To use a property whose name is not a valid literal, you can use bracketed notation:

```
var nonveg = DealsJSON["Non Veg"];
```

Details: In JavaScript, you can access an object property in two ways:

1. Dot notation and a literal for the name, e.g. `obj.foo`.
2. Bracketed notation and a *string* for the name, e.g. `obj["foo"]`. And the string doesn't have to be just a string literal, it can be the result of any expression.

Separately, this is suspect:

```
if (amountObj['specialDeal'] == true) {
```

Comparing things to `true` with `==` in JavaScript is usually not a good idea. If you just want to know if `specialDeal` has a value that isn't `0`, `false`, `""`, `undefined`, or `null` (and it can't be `undefined`, JSON doesn't support that), just remove the comparison:

```
if (amountObj['specialDeal']) {
```

or of course

```
if (amountObj.specialDeal) {
```

Also note that in your JSON, `specialDeal` is given as a *string*. If the string is always blank for things that aren't special deals, that's fine, because blank strings are falsey. But if the string may contain, for instance, `"false"`, you have to be careful, because the **string** `"false"` is not `false`. We'd have to see an example of other possible values in order to advise you how to deal with that, but if it's always `""` for false and some other string for true, the above is fine.

If I [change your JSON](http://jsbin.com/axusin/1/edit#javascript) to have a `specialDeal` that's `true`, this code with the mods listed above works fine: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/eyecak/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/eyecak/1/edit)

```
var nonveg = DealsJSON["Non Veg"];
for (var key in nonveg) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nonveg[key].length; i++) {
    var amountObj = nonveg[key][i];
    if (amountObj.specialDeal) {
      display("Found store: " + amountObj.Store);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As per the json the specialDeal will be shown only for any one which has a deal and in that case the value will be true. For the other objects the option specialDeal wont be present.

Comment: @JohnJohny: `specialDeal` is clearly present, with the value `""`, in the JSON you've quoted. Separately: I've added a live, working example. Hope this helps.

Comment: One more thing. see the Non Veg object does not contain an array it. The objects inside that are not given in [] but given inside {}. Does that matter?

Comment: @JohnJohny: See my answer to that question where you originally asked it.

Comment: Thanks crowder. But can i see the json which you had passed to the JS in live example?

Comment: I tried it with above code and passsed the same json Bt var nonveg = DealsJSON["Non Veg"] is coming as undefined.

Comment: @JohnJohny: The live example I posted is using exactly the JSON you originally quoted, and working correctly. You'll have to do some good, old-fashioned debugging.